# Why is my "Alocasia amazonia" leaf yellowing and drooping?

Tags: identification, diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care, repotting

Got the plant a week ago in a pot with 4 other plants. I propagated them all into one individual pot each. Suddenly, one of the leaves on one of the plants broke and the leaf starts yellowing. The other leaves start dropping.[image]

Comment: Good question and good illustration; if could include an overall illustration & illustration of the top & other leaves, overall height, current watering amount & frequency, current nutrient amount(if any), average daytime & average night time temperatures, size of container, soil used, and if some coarse gravel in the bottom and a hole in the bottom for good aereation & drainage, and an illustration of the other 3 plants, could also be helpful. We encourage you to browse through the Help center, to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Comment: There are some tiny white flecks on the leaf with the damaged area, third vein down on the right. Inspect closely to see what they are and check all leaves (including the backs) and stems for signs of infestation. Not sure what they are, but they look mealy, so maybe mealybug?